# error: called object ‘0’ is not a function

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I receive the following error for my code (client.c):

```
make
gcc -Wall -c client.c -o client.o
client.c: In function ‘main’:
client.c:34: error: called object ‘0’ is not a function
client.c:41: error: called object ‘1’ is not a function
make: *** [client.o] Error 1
```

Here's the code reduced to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "udp.h"
#include "mfs.h"
#include "msg.h"
#include <sys/select.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (4096)

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

msg_t msg;

int main(void)
{

    int rc = MFS_Init("mumble-02.cs.wisc.edu", 100022);

    printf("CLIENT:: about to send message (%d)\n", rc);

    rc = MFS_Lookup(10, "hello");
    printf("Lookup returned: %d\n", rc);

    return 0;
}
```

The headers could still be reduced in number (`<stdio.h>`, `"msg.h"` and `"mfs.h"` are the ones likely to be necessary for this to be a true SSCCE).

Here's the original code — the line numbers from the compilation apply to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "udp.h"
#include "mfs.h"
#include "msg.h"
#include <sys/select.h>

/* According to earlier standards */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>



#define BUFFER_SIZE (4096)

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

msg_t msg;



int main(void)
{
    /*
    int sd = UDP_Open(-1);
    assert(sd > -1);


    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    int rc = UDP_FillSockAddr(&saddr, "mumble-14.cs.wisc.edu", 100022);
    assert(rc == 0);
    */
//  msg.type = 100;
    int rc = MFS_Init("mumble-02.cs.wisc.edu", 100022);




    printf("CLIENT:: about to send message (%d)\n", rc);

    rc = MFS_Lookup(10, "hello");
    printf("Lookup returned: %d\n", rc);
    //    char message[BUFFER_SIZE];
    //  sprintf(message, "hello world");
/*  rc = UDP_Write(sd, &saddr, (char*)&msg, sizeof(  msg));
    // printf("CLIENT:: sent message (%d)\n", rc);

    struct timeval t;
    t.tv_sec=10;
    t.tv_usec=1;
    fd_set r;
    FD_ZERO(&r);
    FD_SET(sd, &r);

    rc=select(sd+1,&r,NULL,NULL,&t);
    if (rc <= 0)
        printf("timeout \n");


    if (rc > 0) {
        struct sockaddr_in raddr;
        int rc = UDP_Read(sd, &raddr, (char*)&msg,sizeof(msg));
        printf("CLIENT:: read %d bytes (message: '%d')\n", rc, msg.type);
    }
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Also here's the Makefile:

```
CC   = gcc
OPTS = -Wall

all: server client libmfs.so

server: server.o udp.o
        $(CC) -o server server.o udp.o 

client: client.o mfs.o udp.o
        $(CC) -lmem -L. -o client client.o mfs.o udp.o 

mfs: mfs.o
        $(CC) -o mfs mfs.o 

libmfs.so: mfs.o udp.o
        $(CC) -c fpic mfs.c udp.c -Wall -Werror
        $(CC) -shared -o libmfs.so mfs.o udp.o 

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(OPTS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f server.o udp.o client.o mfs.o  server client libmfs.so
```

And when I `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` here's the output:
`/afs/cs.wisc.edu/u/j/a/jalal/fall2013/p5-linux/:/afs/cs.wisc.edu/u/j/a/jalal/fall2013/p5-linux/:/scratch.1/jalal/postgresql/lib/:/scratch.1/jalal/postgresql/lib/:/scratch.1/jalal/postgresql/lib/:`

in which `/afs/cs.wisc.edu/u/j/a/jalal/fall2013/p5-linux/` is the path to my project files. My best guess is that there's something wrong in the process of linking in Makefile as it seems client.c can't find mfs.h function prototypes which are defined in mfs.c. Here's the list of files in my project directory:
bare.img  client.c  example.c  example.img  main.c  Makefile  mfs.c  mfscat*  mfs.h  mfsput*  msg.h  server.c  tester.c  udp.c  udp.h

Please let me know what I am possibly missing in my Makefile and how to fix it.

Comment: How are `MFS_Init` and `MFS_Lookup` defined or declared?

Comment: Dump the preprocessed output (change your `-c` to `-E`).  Then review the contents of `client.o`.  Faulting lines mention `MFS_Init` and `MFS_Lookup`, those might not be defined to what you expect.  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should not be a factor.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my Makefile to the following

```
CC   = gcc
OPTS = -Wall

all: server client libmfs.so

server: server.o udp.o
        $(CC) -o server server.o udp.o 
libmfs.so: mfs.o udp.o
        $(CC) -c -fpic mfs.c udp.c -Wall -Werror
        $(CC) -shared -o libmfs.so mfs.o udp.o 

client: client.o mfs.o udp.o libmfs.so
        $(CC) -lmfs -L. -o client client.o mfs.o udp.o 

mfs: mfs.o
        $(CC) -o mfs mfs.o 

#all: server client libmfs.so

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(OPTS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f server.o udp.o client.o mfs.o  server client libmfs.so
```

And also changed the following lines in msg.h:

```
#define INIT    0
#define LOOKUP   1
#define STAT     2
#define WRITE    3
#define READ     4
#define CREAT    5
#define UNLINK   6
#define SHUTDOWN 7
```

as they were previously the same name as my prototypes in mfs.h
Now it's fixed.